# Emacs: create a custom pinbar tabbar

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like to create a custom pinbar or tabbar (a bar anyway) where a specific set of frequently accessed files is shown. I really want bar not filesets etc.

I went through the pinbar.el and tabbar.el however my limited knowledge of emacs lisp doesn't allow me to see the function with which the creation of this bar is done. I can understand how I can add items, delete them etc, but I how I create one in the first place specifying position, height, etc ?

Can you please help me?

Comment: Those are not standard libraries in Emacs. Please provide links.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the Emacs tool-bar for this?

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Tool-Bar.html

You could add entries to the tool-bar for the files you want. I'm not sure what the files you want are... perhaps the easiest way would be to store the files as bookmarks:

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Bookmarks.html

and then display the first few bookmarks in the toolbar?